# How to create (web)server on localhost with android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server, webserver

I have a question on how to create a [localhost](http://localhost/) (web)server in android application using Java. I use [android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). I would like the server to retrieve files from a specific folder and allow it to work with [PHP](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and [JavaScript](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own HTTP server using [ServerSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html).
JavaScript is client side, and it is impossible to use PHP in your own Java web server unless you are able to write your own PHP compiler.